# pg_restore a view

Tags: postgresql

What's the best way to restore a view?

1. `pg_dump -h hostname -d databasename -Fc > db.dump`
2. `DROP VIEW viewname;`
3. `pg_restore -h hostname -d databasename -t viewname db.dump`  This does not error, but also doesn't seem to work.  Have also tried it with the `-n` schema option.  In verbose mode, it says *pg_resore: implied data-only restore*.

Is it possible to restore a view via *pg_restore*

Comment: Hm, that's ugly. I don't see why `-t` should imply `--data-only`, especially when `-n` does not. I'll raise this on pgsql-bugs.

Comment: @CraigRinger, thank you.  Restoring from the full dump works, but I wanted to be selective with the *view* and wasn't sure if I was doing something wrong.

Comment: As a workaround you can do a `--schema-only` dump without the `-d` dbname argument, to a text file. Then edit it to extract just the view definition. I'm looking at this now and will post a link to the bugs post when done.

Comment: I was dumping as SQL inserts before and manually restoring, but I was hoping to avoid some of this manual processing (oh well) :)

Comment: As a workaround: why don't you use `select pg_get_viewdef('viewname')` to extract the source of the view? I don't think pg_dump does it any different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PostgreSQL 9.4 or older there does not appear to be a way to do this.

[Here's the issue report I just posted](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMsr+YGJ50TvTVK4Dbp66gAjeOC0KaP6KXFEHAOM+neQmHvoQA@mail.gmail.com).

If you want to patch pg_restore it looks pretty trivial, just add checking for under the test for `ropt->selTypes` in `_tocEntryRequired` (in `pg_backup_archiver.c`), changing:

```
                   strcmp(te->desc, "TABLE DATA") == 0)
```

to

```
                   strcmp(te->desc, "TABLE DATA") == 0 ||
                   strcmp(te->desc, "VIEW") == 0)
```

Here's the full patch: https://gist.github.com/ringerc/1743cfad34694fc9b9a3

You don't have to compile and install all of PostgreSQL for this, you can just compile a custom `pg_restore` if you want.

*update*: [Here's the -hackers post with the proposed patch](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAMsr+YGKmAA4qdpo6FsrH5HkNT-LThiJrTSaLHOG2LRRdaKbow@mail.gmail.com).

*update2*: This is now fixed in 9.6 according to [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgrestore.html#APP-PGRESTORE-OPTIONS)

Answer (score 0):

I have too not figured out a solution for this.

Instead I tried to create a list out of backupfile and exported the list to a notepad file.
Later with -L parameter in pg_restore I restored the component.